# How to get divs to go under each other

Tags: html, css

Im using the same div class for two buttons but they go next to each other instead of under one another.

My CSS is

```
.viewproj {
background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
padding: 0.6% 0.3% 0.8% 1.3%;
width: 160px;
border-radius: 3px;
float: right;
}
```

My HTML is

```
<a class="proj" href="Habbogold/habbogoldlivedemo.html"> 
<div class="viewproj">View Live Demo</div></a>

<a class="proj" href="purchase.php">
<div class="viewproj">Purchase</div></a>
```

I've tried adding`display: block;` and `display: list-item;` to the CSS but it doesn't change. When I add `<br />` after the first div, the second one goes down `100px`  because I have some images next to it.

Comment: The placement depends on the size of container. If you want to place them one after the other the container has to be in the size of the button div.

Comment: you are using float:right; (1.remove it 2.find alternative 3.??? 4.profit

Comment: can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push them to stack by adding a:

```
clear: both;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6up80xje/

For more info on clear property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper around your links (see http://jsfiddle.net/cx7bqa37/)

HTML

```
<div class="example_wrapper">
    <a class="proj" href="Habbogold/habbogoldlivedemo.html"> 
        <div class="viewproj">View Live Demo</div>
    </a>

    <a class="proj" href="purchase.php">
        <div class="viewproj">Purchase</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.viewproj {
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    padding: 0.6% 0.3% 0.8% 1.3%;
    width: 160px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.example_wrapper {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add [`clear:both`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bjte7jk1/)

```
.viewproj {
background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
padding: 0.6% 0.3% 0.8% 1.3%;
width: 160px;
border-radius: 3px;
float: right;
clear:both
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ChwnA)

```
.viewproj {
background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
padding: 0.6% 0.3% 0.8% 1.3%;
width: 160px;
border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
float: right;

}
.viewproj:first-child {
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want have two buttons beneath them and if they position on the right side of page u need create another container. This new container should have a float: right. Buttons should not float because they set in one line.